# PhpMyAdmin: What does the number next to a primary A_I column means?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I was wondering this since a guy was here checking my database and he expanded the primary column and grimmed a bit.

This is the screenshot of what I mean:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number next the column in phpMyAdmin is the order of the `ORDER BY`, in some cases you can have more than one field in the `ORDER BY` clause and they will numbered.

Example:

[image: ORDER BY multiple fields]